# HTML Newsletter show different <td> 's in mobile and desktop

Tags: html, newsletter

I am coding an email newsletter.

I want to show a `<td>` with a height of `400px` on desktop but then reduce down on mobile to say `200px`.

I don't want to use media queries for this as they don't work on some email clients and I want to get it working on as many email clients as possible.

Would anyone be able to offer help as to the best way of doing this. I was thinking of having a mobile show / mobile hide on two separate `<td>`s with the same content but just different height's given for the inline style.

Is there a way of doing this fully inline without the need for style in the header/media queries.

Comment: Media queries should work in HTML email on modern phones. Pretty much all desktop HTML email clients are great - it's just Microsoft Office Outlook that's awful - and that doesn't run on Mobile so you're fine.

Comment: @Dai Well, I happen to have a Windows phone with Outlook on it.

Comment: @Dai — https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/microsoft-outlook/id951937596?mt=8

Comment: @Quentin Outlook on iOS and Android uses the phone's native WebView (a Safari or Chrome view) to render HTML emails. I'm talking about desktop Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010, Outlook 2013, Outlook 2016, and Outlook 2019 that all use Office Word (seriously) to render HTML emails.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries, despite your reluctance to use them, are your best option.

The only other tools which can dynamically adjust based on the height of something are:

- Percentage lengths … which don't let you pick between two fixed heights and which depend on the container not having `height: auto`
- JavaScript … which no email client will execute.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use media queries because there is no magic - JavaScript is not available to use.

Alternatively you could create an A/B test for the two versions of your newsletter (Desktop & Mobile) with a link to an online alternate version (Desktop -> Mobile / Mobile -> Desktop). Use analytics determine whether or not the format is a factor and you could also identify which platform is most widely used, etc. The world is your oyster as they say but it seems like overkill - keep it simple and just use media queries.

There are a few resources online to help you with the media queries:

https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/

https://cm.engineering/fixing-bugs-with-outlook-specific-css-f4b8ae5be4f4